# asp.net-mvc and webforms co-existing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

We have a massive client facing web application here.  We recently re-wrote the buy online experiance to make it quicker.  My suggestion of using ASP.Net-MVC was not taken on board as I'm kinda the only one here that knows about it.

Now we are about to embark on redeveloping another section of the site and again I can't use MVC because no one here, no matter how many times you ask them, has bothered to research the framework.

Rather than be left behind and out in the cold again, I'd really like to re-write the sections in the MVC framework.

I think I could get away with it if I could mix WebForms and MVC but there seems to be little literature on the technique.

I'd need to be able to go to MVC pages from WebForm pages and vice-versa seamlessly.

Ive read [this article](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc) and it's great but are there any more about?

Has anyone actually done this and deployed it successfuly?  I'd like to hear any war stories, techniques, tips, tricks and gotchas.

I'm looking for as much literature as I can get my hands on so that when the project kicks off I can present a convincing case to the powers that be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excellent question.  WebForm compatibility is a real selling point for ASP.NET-MVC.

Comment: I've heard that but can't really find a great deal on it.  If I get a lot of replies then I'll consider making this a community wiki as I think, in this transition phase, there are going to be lots more people in the same tank.

Comment: Honestly, I just imported some web-forms into my MVC project. I had to create a mirrored master page for my web-forms. You can't use the MVC master page for web-forms. and if you can I haven't found a way. Its pretty seamless tho, I thought it would be difficult, but it pretty much just worked immeditately.

Comment: You're welcome, @griegs. I was expecting a few more answers to this question since hybrid sites are such an important part of an ASP.NET MVC migration path. Good luck!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Chapter 12 in [Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470384611) is called **Best of Both Worlds: Web Forms and MVC Together**. It covers exactly the issue you raise.  The good news is that there is not a lot to it.  The book was written by team rock-stars Rob Conery, Scott Hanselman, Phil Haack, and Scott Guthrie.  I found it instrumental when learning ASP.NET MVC.

Also, here's an article called [**Integrating ASP.Net MVC Into An Existing ASP.Net Web Application**](http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/MGodfrey/archive/2009/03/31/663.aspx) that discusses it.

**UPDATE**:  Turns out that you can download a copy of the draft [**Best of Both Worlds**](http://media.wiley.com/assets/1539/15/professionalaspnet35mvc_chapter13.pdf) chapter for **free**.  This is an "Uncorrected Draft - Not Final Book Chapter" but might be worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence.  Looks like I'm hitting the boss up for a book or two.

Comment: Thanks again @Lawrence.  You've provided some fantastic links here and am now busy going through the chapter with a test WebForms site.

Comment: The "Integrating ASP.Net MVC Into An Existing ASP.Net Web Application" link appears to be broken